# Check if two queries are the same

Tags: solr, lucene

I have quite a big index and quite high frequency of queries.
To reduce number of requests to Solr i want to see if two queries are the same or one is subquery of another one **without** running them

**For example**:
Fun and Friday == Friday and Fun != Fun or Friday

Funny is subquery of Fun*

and etc. Any ideas? mb with analysers or smth?

Cheers

Comment: Just to clear this up: Are you sure that `Fun and Friday` is the same as `Friday and Fun`? I am asking in terms of `Relevance`. Usually Solr treats the first word of a search as more important than the second. Thus the first search would have top docs more related to `Fun` and the other more relate to `Friday` ...

Comment: Generally u r right, but in the industry im in, relevance is usually ignored, it is the total return set that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the parsed query object for equality. To ignore the order of the boolean clauses, you need to specifiy your own comparator for that. In the same way, you should be able to check whether a query is a subquery of another. I did this a while ago for exactly the same reason you have and it worked quite well.

Here is a small sample code for comparing queries when the order of the clauses are not important:

```
public boolean areEqualsOrderNotImportant(Query q1, Query q2) {
    if((q1 instanceof BooleanQuery) && (q2 instanceof BooleanQuery)) {
        BooleanQuery bq1 = (BooleanQuery)q1;
        BooleanQuery bq2 = (BooleanQuery)q2;
        if(bq1.getClauses().length!=bq2.getClauses().length) {
            return false;
        }
        for(BooleanClause clause: bq1.getClauses()) { //multiple occurence of same clause not handled
            if(!contains(bq2.getClauses(), clause)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }else {
        return q1.equals(q2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have maybe an example of code for that, pls?

Comment: For what exactly? The code for the whole functionality would be too much.

Comment: For queries comparison?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle this is to normalize the two items (put them into a standard order), then perform the compare (like sorting 2 files, then comparing the sorted files to find the differences).

In your case, you would have to parse the queries, put them in a standard order, then perform the comparison. I don't know of any tools off-hand within Lucene to help with this, though.